# How to handle PageExpiredException

Tags: java, exception, wicket

In Wicket 1.5.3, I want to handle the `PageExpiredException` with a suitable response page. The `PageExpiredException` is thrown when one accesses an url which is mounted as a non-bookmarkable page, so that's quite possible.

Now when I try to redirect to my Login page: `setResponsePage(Login.class)` the same exception is thrown.

Comment: Be careful to make sure that your ExceptionPage and your redirected page are not themselves throwing an exception.  I know that's very basic advice, but I've seen people confused by it before.

Comment: You're right, that's what I thought of too. It seems that I have solved the problem now, gonna write an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mounted my `RuntimeExceptionPage` as a bookmarkable page and added an empty constructor to the class. Now the link to my response page works.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the PageExpiredPage using [`IApplicationSettings.setPageExpiredErrorPage(Class<C> pageExpiredErrorPage)`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/settings/IApplicationSettings.html#setPageExpiredErrorPage%28java.lang.Class%29)

Comment: Actually I catch all exceptions with a `CustomRequestListener` and show a custom Error Page regardless of the actual exception. My question is why I can't redirect to another page after the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like ur CustomRequestListener was throwning the RuntimeExceptionPage when u redirected to ur custom expired page, so u were getting stuck in a sort of loop. Seems strange that you expire a page if its not bookmarkable. Why dont u use wicket authorization http://wicketstuff.org/wicket13/authorization/, it handles this kind of stuff for u. You can even use handy annotations to implement it on pages.

Comment: Thank you, see my answer... and my newly opened question.